# ObjectInputStream cannot cast correctly object

Tags: java, android

I have 2 classes. In first class, I write a data from List, in the second class, I want read this data and put into listview. It save a data correctly, but when I try to get it, logcat give a error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOnline$podzialPlanu cannot be cast to pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOffline$podzialPlanu
            at pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOffline$AdapterDlaPlanu.getView(AdapterPlanuProbOffline.java:115)
```

I can't understand why, because always I get the same type of data.

First class write method:

```
public void SaveAsFile(List<podzialPlanu> lista){
// lista - List<podzialPlanu> podzialPlanuList2 = new ArrayList<podzialPlanu>();

        try {
            FileOutputStream saveFile = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "planProby.sav");
            ObjectOutputStream save = new ObjectOutputStream(saveFile);

            save.writeObject(lista);

            save.close();


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

And the main class, when I try to get data from this file, and put it into my listview

```
public class AdapterPlanuProbOffline extends Activity implements Serializable {

    List<String> DzienDataList;
    List<String> GodzinaList;
    List<String> RodzajList;
    List<String> ProgramList;
    List<String> UwagiList;
    List<String> listaDni;
    List<String> listaMiesiecy;
    File plik;


    public class podzialPlanu implements Serializable{
        String DzienData;
        String Godzina;
        String Rodzaj;
        String Program;
        String Uwagi;
    }

    AdapterDlaPlanu nowyAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listviewy);



        nowyAdapter = new AdapterDlaPlanu();

        ListView listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        listView1.setAdapter(nowyAdapter);

    }



    public class AdapterDlaPlanu extends BaseAdapter implements Serializable{

        List<podzialPlanu> podzialPlanuList = getData();

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return podzialPlanuList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return podzialPlanuList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if(convertView == null){
               LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) AdapterPlanuProbOffline.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
               convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.planproby,parent,false);
            }



            TextView DzienDataTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dzienDataTextView);
            TextView GodzinaTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.godzinaTextView);
            TextView RodzajZajecTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rodzajzajecTextView);
            TextView ProgramTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.programTextView);
            TextView UwagiTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uwagiTextView);




/// here is a problem with getData() method
    DzienDataTextView.setText(getData().get(position).DzienData);
    GodzinaTextView.setText(getData().get(position).Godzina);
    RodzajZajecTextView.setText(getData().get(position).Rodzaj);
    ProgramTextView.setText(getData().get(position).Program);
    UwagiTextView.setText(getData().get(position).Uwagi);



            return convertView;
        }

        public podzialPlanu getPodzialPlanu(int position){
            return podzialPlanuList.get(position);
        }
    }




    public List<podzialPlanu> getData()  {

        List<podzialPlanu> podzialPlanuList2 = new ArrayList<podzialPlanu>();
        List< List<String> > listaGlowna = new ArrayList<List<String>>();


        for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
            listaGlowna.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }

        DzienDataList = new ArrayList<String>();
        GodzinaList = new ArrayList<String>();
        RodzajList = new ArrayList<String>();
        ProgramList = new ArrayList<String>();
        UwagiList = new ArrayList<String>();
        listaDni = new ArrayList<String>();
        listaMiesiecy = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" + "planProby.sav");
            ObjectInputStream restore = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            podzialPlanuList2 = (List<podzialPlanu>) restore.readObject();

            restore.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StreamCorruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return podzialPlanuList2;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, lets look at the exception message:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
          pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOnline$podzialPlanu 
cannot be cast to 
          pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOffline$podzialPlanu
```

Do you see the difference?  Notice that there are two different `podzialPlanu` classes.

Now if the `SaveAsFile` method in your Question is the one that created the serialization, then it follows that the `List<podzialPlanu>` argument type is actually referring to a:

```
   pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOnline.podzialPlanu
```

rather than

```
   pl.pawelfrydrych.CHAPS.AdapterPlanuProbOffline.podzialPlanu
```

---

> Yes, so what should I do? If is there serialization, then I can't get this data in another class?

OK, so the real problem is not serialization.  You would have the same problem if you skipped the serialize / deserialize step.

The fact is that those two nested classes are *unrelated*.  You cannot cast between unrelated classes.  So you either need to:

- use just one inner class
- cast to the correct inner class, or
- make the inner classes related (e.g. using a common interface or superclass) and cast to the common supertype.

Assuming that the inner classes are `public`, you shouldn't have "access" problems.

Comment: Yes, so what should I do? If is there serialization, then I can't get this data in another class?